# Problem on convergence of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given that $\lim f_n=1>0$, Show that there exists a positive integer $m$ such that $f_n\ge 0  \\ \forall n \ge m  $

Comment: @CameronBuie its lim of f_n sorry, fixed it

Comment: What is your definition of convergence? If you just write it down, you should almost have solved your problem.

Comment: yes, $|f_n-1|<\epsilon \forall n \ge m$ How do i get to show that each term $f_n$ is $\ge 0$ ? I an not able to get this part

Comment: Choose sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, and this is guaranteed, since what you're saying is "$f_n$ is within $\epsilon$ of $1$ for all $n\ge m$."

Comment: @CameronBuie I still don't see it :(

Comment: @Aman Maybe you should try to draw that condition on a graph to get a better understanding. $|f_n-1|\leq\epsilon$ means that $f_n$ is inside the line segment $[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]$. If this is true for any $n$ after a certain point, how can you chose $\epsilon$ to make sure that every $f_n$ is greater than $0$?

Comment: I do not understand the votes the close. It would be useful if those voting to close could give the OP some feedback. Currently, from the OPs point of view this question is being closed because "We know how to answer it, it is *dead* easy! So you should be able to answer it too! Therefore, we are closing this question." (In case anyone is wondering, this is *not* a valid reason for closing...)

Comment: @user1729  I would like to add that most questions that any student asks here are answered, that is the reason why we come here. It is simple for many probably coz they have done this many times and understand it and that is exactly what i am trying to do !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aman, simply employ the usual definition of convergence. If $f_n \to 1$, then for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $m \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \geq m$, $|f_n - 1| < \epsilon$. Moreover, $|f_n - 1| < \epsilon$ is equivalent to $-\epsilon < f_n - 1 < \epsilon$, so $1 - \epsilon < f_n < 1 + \epsilon$, i.e., $f_n \geq 0$.

Comment: The OP mistyped the post. It is now corrected.

Comment: @glebovg That means that in this question the condition holds good from the initial definition itself , ok, but what if instead of $1$ $f_n \rightarrow l$ ? Then $]l-\epsilon<f_n<l+\epsilon[$ what can we say about $m$ ?

Comment: We can claim that $m$ exists because $f_n$ converges to $l$. Again, simply use the standard definition of convergence.

Comment: That cleared it for me. Thanks

Comment: if $f_n\to l$ then $\epsilon = \frac{l}{2}$ works to show $f_n\ge 0$

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal No. Consider $l < 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the definition of $\lim_{n->\infty}f_n=a$ is ([wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence)):

> For each real number $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that, for every $n > N$, we have $|f_n - a| < \epsilon$.

Setting, for example, $\epsilon=0.5$ results in that there exists a natural number $m$, such that for all $n>m$, $|f_n-1|<0.5$, which implies $-0.5<f_n-1<0.5$ and thus $0<0.5<f_n<1.5$.